# Adding a bar above a full screen PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, content-type

I'm currently displaying a PDF using header type application/pdf and readfile for the pdf itself.

I need to add a bar at the top of the pdf with a button on.

The issue is that the PDF is currently the whole screen and there is any html behind it.

Is there a way this can be done?

I've looked on google but can't find a way this has been done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `<iframe>`. You put your regular HTML followed by the `<iframe>` pointing to your PDF file. Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%;height:50px;">Top Bar with a <button>here</button></div>
<iframe src="pdffile.php" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the PDF should show as full screen still? Should I include the content type within the iframe to ensure it's not downloaded?

Comment: Yes, the `pdffile.php` should have `header('Content-type: application/pdf');`

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing, you are embedding the usual pdf that loads full screen within an iframe. Got you!